# Database problem--student registering for the same class twice..how to stop it Access 20007

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access-2007

I am making a mock database and I have a `student` table, `student_class` linking table, and a `class` table.  How can I make it so that a student cannot be registered for the same class twice?

Example: StudentID 21 and classID 34 can be entered X number of times in the linking table.

The tables are designed 3NF, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your student_class linking table (otherwise called a composite table), make both values, StudentID and ClassID, primary keys.  So that table will have 2 columns that are composite primary keys and also foreign keys to their associated tables.  Does that make sense?

Comment: aahh yes it does.  so i have them right now as just ints.  and if i make them primary keys they shouldn't be able to be registered twice?  so..it wouldn't matter that the table had three primary keys?

Comment: @dzilla: What is the third primary key?

Comment: access automatically generates a primary key for a table.  but i just made a composite key of both fields and didn't even think that the now useless ID field is still in there.  :)

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with your database

Comment: Access does NOT automatically generate a surrogate key, unless you tell it to. In this case, there's no utility in adding the surrogate key at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a table that tells you which students are enrolled in which classes, named `students_classes`. If you make a composite primary key on this table containing student_id and class_id, then it should be impossible to have the database contain a student in the same class twice.

I should point out that you should *not* have an auto-increment ID primary key column on this table (I think Access likes to add this by default so if it did you may have to remove it). If you do, you could still end up with duplicates if all three are a part of the key. Example:

```
ID   student_id    class_id

113          1           2
114          1           2
```

Having the `ID` field still allows you have a student enrolled twice in the same class.

Comment: ok, so take the primary key of the linking table and copy it into a new table, or make a composite primary key or does it matter?

Comment: hot damn, stackoverflow is helpful :).  i can't believe i totally blanked on this...

Answer (score 1):

A student_class table probably has at least two columns. One would be a foreign key to the primary key in student; the other would be a foreign key to the primary key in class. You need a primary key constraint on that pair of columns.

For example, if student_class had the two columns student_id and class_id . . .

- Open the table student_class in design view.
- Select *both* those columns.
- Click the key icon.

That should do it.

Comment: so i need to just make them both primary keys, but not change the joins?

Comment: Make two columns *the* primary key. You can only have one primary key per table, but the primary key can have more than one column. (The Access user interface will make it *look* like two separate primary keys, but that's not what it actually does.) And you shouldn't need to change the joins. (Better to call them "relationships" when you're in table design or in the Relationships window.)